# insert multiple char * into a const char* with pre filled text

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

i have setup a working mysql connector for my c++ project. Now i'm making a login for registered users.

i want to get the username and password into the SQLquery string.

i am trying to get this working:
currently its displaying noting and the game crashes.

```
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp" //boost
#include <cgl\cgl.h> // game library (core media library)
#include <sstream> // sstream
char* username=DEFSER;
char* password=PASS12345;
const char *SQLquery;

std::string SQLquery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(username) + "' AND PassWord='" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(password) + "'");
```

what i want to get out of SQLquery:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='DEFSER' AND PassWord='PASS12345'
```

and i execute it in this way:

```
res = stmt->executeQuery(SQLquery);
```

this is not a fully working code i only want to know how i can get the username and password into the SQLquery.

error when i try to run the query:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'SQLquery' is being used without being initialized.
```

Comment: so you say i can try this? 
std::string SQLquery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='" + username + "' AND PassWord='" + password + "'");

Comment: just post the whole & updated code you're trying to compile (if it's too big, try a smaller version reproducing the problem)

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is not concatenating strings, you are adding `std::string` objects to a literal string pointer.

The [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class handles [concatenation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) of C-style strings just fine without any `lexical_cast`, so just do e.g.

```
std::string SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='" +
    username + "' AND PassWord='" + password + "'";
```

---

After testing the above solution doesn't actually work for me. But the following does:

```
std::string SQLQuery = (std::ostringstream() << "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='"
    << username << "' AND PassWord='" << password << "'").str();
```

Comment: Not to mention that `SQLquery` is first defined as a `const char*`

Comment: i get this error:
error expression must have integral or enum type

Comment: yes, but username and password are char*, so adding char* won't work.

Comment: get rid of `const char *SQLquery;`, change username and password from char* to std::string, and this solution will work.

Comment: i get this error in res = stmt->executeQuery(SQLquery);
Error: identifier "SQLquery" is undefined

Comment: @user3660885 don't forget to put quotes around your name & password : `std::string username("DEFSER");` ...

Comment: yes i did, but it gives me this error: 
 error C2065: 'username' : undeclared identifier
 error C2065: 'password' : undeclared identifier